# How to see if my database contains a user with a given username and password with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a web application which includes some simple user management with Java EE 7 and Hibernate. I am in the early stages and I'm currently writing the persistence layer (?).  I need to write a method that checks if there is a user who has a username and password as given. 
My first thought was to use the EntityManager's contains() method, but that one receives an entity and because of that it will compare IDs, too. But of course my IDs automatically incremented and I do not know the ID of the given user which needs to be authenticated, so it always returns false. Even when the username and password fields are equal, the ID field will always differ.

This was my second thought:

```
public boolean isUser(String username, String password) {
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("findUser");

    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("password", password);

    try {
       query.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This failed, too because for some reason it never raised a NoResultException, even when the size of the result list was 0.

This is my final thought:

```
public boolean isUser(String username, String password) {
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("findUser");

    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("password", password);

    return query.getResultList().size() != 0;
}
```

This works, but I was hoping to see if there are better patterns to do such a thing with Hibernate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: NoResultException is never thrown by getResultList(), as the javadoc indicates. It's thrown by getSingleResult(). If all you need to know is if there is such a user, you could use a `select count(...)` query, returning a number of rows rather than a user, but it wouldn't make a big difference. Note that storing passwords in clear-text in a database is a bad, bad idea. Passwords should be salted and hashed.

Comment: I know, but this is just a dummy text

Comment: Have you considered using Java EE Security? Check out [Java Security Quickstart](https://github.com/karlnicholas/javaee-security-quickstart-archetype) archetype. It may solve many of the problems you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Finding a single result

You can try [`Query#getSingleResult()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult--), as following:

```
public User findUser(String username, String password) {

    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("findUser");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("password", password);

    return (User) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

The above method will throw [`NoResultException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NoResultException.html) if there is no result and [`NonUniqueResultException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NonUniqueResultException.html) if more than one result.

It's always good to remember that you must *never* store passwords as plain strings in the database. Passwords must be encoded using [strong hashing functions](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/).

### Java EE Security

When talking about security, I'd like to recommend you another solution. I don't know your requirements, but it seems you are reinventing the wheel. Don't do that unless you *really* know what you are doing. Have you ever considered Java EE Security?

Here are a few good resources to start:

- [DZone Refcard #099: Getting Started With Java EE Security](https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-java-ee)
- [The Java EE Tutorial: Security](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partsecurity.htm#GIJRP)
- [Java EE 7 Samples: BASIC Authetication](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/servlet/security-basicauth)
- [Java EE 7 Samples: FORM Authentication](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/servlet/security-form-based)
- [WildFly Quickstart: Servlet Security](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/servlet-security)
- [WildFly Quickstart: EJB Security](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/ejb-security)

### Spring Security

Is Spring in your stack? Why don't you try [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)?

Here are a few resources:

- [Spring Guides: Securing a Web Application](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)
- [Spring Security Guides](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/)
- [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Answer (score 0):

It is also never a good idea for security reasons to have the username column not unique and then you always could use the getSingleResult method. Also for performance reason is the getResultList + size method not a good idea, because you have to fetch all records only for a exists check. And I think it is also a design failure because if you can have the same user with same password multiple, then how do you can identify the correct user and so the GetSingleResult method can always be used also with non unique usernames. As tip save also the user entity within a session bean or directly within the session, because you will need the entity informations normally much more often in web applications and so you do not have to query multiple times for the user data.

Like Nicholas said if you want use JEE, then have a look at all features like JAAS. But it depends little bit on your Container to give you a better answer. There are also some other Frameworks like PicketLink etc. which you could use.